# Network Caller ID on iOS without a computer

Tags: ios, caller-id

[Network Caller ID (or NCID)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Caller_ID) allows incoming call information for a regular landline telephone to be sent over a local network to display on computers and other devices. There are programs for OS X that can handle this, and there's even one [solution](http://nowhereman999.wordpress.com/2011/02/09/prowl-and-ncid-callerid-forwarded-to-your-iphone/) that broadcasts to iOS devices via a computer using the Prowl app.

Is there is a solution to show NCID details on iOS that doesn't involve a computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there didn't seem to be a stand-alone solution, I made a little app that connects to a NCID Server and gets the list of phone numbers:

http://erike.net/ncid/

Unfortunately Apple didn't allow me to keep the connection open in the background, but I may release a fix for this in Cydia.